# OpenGL Bump Map -- Texture artifacts ?

Tags: opengl, textures, shaders, maps

I am learning OpenGL (and learning the math behind it) and I'm making a simple OBJ viewer, nothing fancy.
I have diffuse, specular and ambient light/texture working fine and now I am implementing the bump mapping.
I based my code on what I learned with the OpenGL 4.3 Redbook and "Mathematics for 3D game programming and computer graphics" book.

There is probably something I didn't understand correctly, I just hope you will be able to help me :)

Anyway this is the result I get (from a free asset used just for testing -- the results are fine in blender) :
[image: Results]

This is the diffuse texture and the bump map :
[image: Diffuse texture]
[image: Bump texture]

Fragment shader code :

```
void main() {
    vec3 normalDirection = normalize(tangenteSpace*(texture2D( bump_tex, f_texcoord ).rgb*2.0 - 1.0));
    //vec3 normalDirection = normalize(mat3(invTransp)*vertNormal);
    vec3 viewDirection = tangenteSpace*normalize(vec3(invView * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) - position));

    float attenuation = 1.0;//none
    vec3 vertToLightSource = vec3(light.position - position*light.position.w);
    float distance = length(vertToLightSource);
    attenuation = mix(1.0,1.0/(light.constantAttenuation +
                    light.linearAttenuation *distance +
                    light.quadraticAttenuation*distance*distance),light.position.w);
    vec3 lightDirection = tangenteSpace*(vertToLightSource/distance);

    //spotlight if spotCutoff <= 90
    float clampedCosine = max(0.0, dot(-lightDirection, normalize(light.spotDirection)));
    float tempMix = mix(attenuation * pow(clampedCosine, light.spotExponent),0.0,clampedCosine < cos(light.spotCutoff * 3.14159 / 180.0));//if outside of spotlight nothing
    attenuation = mix(attenuation,tempMix,light.spotCutoff <= 90.0);

    //should there be any attenuation ?
    attenuation = mix(attenuation,1.0,light.position.w);

    //------------------------------ ambiant light
    vec3 ambientLight = vec3(ambientScene)*vec3(mat.Ka);

    //------------------------------ specular light
    //get the reflection
    vec4 specularMapPixel = texture2D(spec_tex, f_texcoord).rgba;
    vec3 specularColor = specularMapPixel.rgb;
    float shininess = specularMapPixel.a;
    vec3 specularReflection = mix(
    attenuation * vec3(light.specular) * vec3(mat.Ks)* pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), viewDirection)),mat.Ns*shininess) *specularColor.rgb,
          vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0
          );

    vec3 diffuseReflection = attenuation*
    vec3(light.diffuse)*vec3(mat.Kd)
    *max(0.0,dot(normalDirection,lightDirection));

    vec4 Color = vec4(vec4(specularReflection,1.0) + vec4(ambientLight,1)*texture2D(amb_tex, f_texcoord) + vec4(diffuseReflection,1.0)*texture2D(dif_tex, f_texcoord));

    FragColor = Color;
}
```

Vertex Shader Code :

```
void main()
{
    //comnpute tangent space
    tangenteSpace[0] = mat3(mv)*normalize(tangent.xyz);
    tangenteSpace[2] = mat3(mv)*normalize(vertNormal);
    tangenteSpace[1] = mat3(mv)*normalize(cross(tangenteSpace[0],tangenteSpace[2])*tangent.w);
    tangenteSpace = transpose(tangenteSpace);

    //position in world space
    position = m * vertCoord;
    f_texcoord = vec2(texCoord);

    gl_Position = mvp * vertCoord;
}
```

Comment: I haven't read the code, but it seems like the alpha component of the colors is getting zeroed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting artefacts is because you are not using a bump map shader; You are using a *normal map* shader, with a displacement map.

A normal map (often confused with bump map) looks like this:

[image]

The colour represents the surface normal, which you then transform from tangent space to view space.

The texture you have shown is a height, or displacement map, which is used to *generate* the normal map.

If you are using GIMP, there is a nice plugin available [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gimp-normalmap/downloads), which will convert a height map to a normal map, and once you bind that resulting texture instead, your artefacts should disappear.